# What is the web browser to use with DAT protocol?(DAT is a newly introduced P2P data transferring mechanism)

Tags: web-browser

What is the browser I can use to view the websites starting with [dat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(web_decentralization_project)) instead of www?
DAT is a protocol which has been introduce a new P2P data transfer mechanism.
I.e those which are not associated with an IP address.

Comment: To quote from [this page](https://macwright.org/2017/07/20/decentralize-your-website.html) "[Beaker Browser](https://beakerbrowser.com/) just launched, a user-friendly browser that transparently supports Dat websites: you can go to dat:// URLs just like you can https:// URLs". So, that seems like an answer.  hopefully thsi question will be reopened.